How to properly check an optional parameter in a Swift function?
In my project I have two needs that can be handled by one of my functions. I figured that an optional parameter would be the best way for that one function to handle two different needs.
What am unsure of is the proper syntax for checking the optional parameter.  Below is the way I figured would be proper, but since am still green I wanted to double check.  Maybe there's a cleaner way? Or maybe there's something inherently wrong with the way I am using it below.
func collectBuffers(sample: Bool?)  {
   ...
   if sample != nil, sample == true {
   ...
   }
}


Your if sample != nil is doing nothing in your code. Delete it. You can just say
if sample == true {

If sample is nil, or non-nil but false, the test will fail, as desired.

In my opinion this is the only situation in which you may compare something to true, i.e. because it is not a Boolean (it's an Optional wrapping a Boolean). In your original code, where you actually want to ask whether sample is nil, I would insist on your writing it this way:
if let sample, sample {

The if let unwraps sample safely, and now you do have a Bool — and there is no need to compare it against true, as you are already saying if and sample is a Bool at this point.

Yeah, it works.  Considering how strict Xcode is on optionals I'm shocked.  But it works and that's enough for me.  Thank you

They are strict but smart. If you compare an Optional to a value of the wrapped type, Swift knows what you mean.

If you opt for the long form I'd even suggest being more verbose, and using if let sample, sample == true. That is easier to understand at a glance than if let sample, sample. But as you say, if sample == true is actually ok in this context.
